# Ошибка при инициализации переменной типа var

Tags: c#

В проекте используются 2 компонента (`listBox`, `metroComboBox`), в которые нужно записать информацию. Для этого использую функцию `UpdateListOfSports`, передавая в качестве параметра объект либо `listBox`, либо `metroComboBox`. При определения типа объекта в самой функции сталкиваюсь с ошибкой **CS0173**, которую описал ниже. Буду очень благодарен, если помогите решить данную проблему.

```
public void UpdateListOfSports(object obj)
{
    DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect();
    DataTable dt = dbConnect.SelectValues("SELECT * FROM sport");
    var list = (obj is ListBox) ? (ListBox)obj : (MetroComboBox)obj; // тут ошибка
    list.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       list.Items.Add(row["KindOfSport"].ToString());
    list.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

> **Ошибка  CS0173**    Не удается определить тип условного выражения, так как неявного преобразования между `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` и
>   `MetroFramework.Controls.MetroComboBox` не существует.

Comment: Ну, а какого типа, как вам кажется, должна быть переменная `list`?

Comment: Это в зависимости от передаваемого параметру. Если передаю listBox1, то соответственно тип ListBox, иначе - MetroComboBox.

Comment: Про строгую типизацию в языке C# слышали? Это вам не это, это вам не тут, это вам не джаваскрипт.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробую на пальцах объяснить. **var** - это не тип. **var** - это просто волшебное слово для ленивых, чтобы не писать нужный тип руками.

Каждый раз, когда вы пишете `var i = 1;` или `var s = "acb";` компилятор подставляет вместо `var` тот тип, который в правой части выражения.

То есть запись `var s = "acb";` абсолютно эквивалентна записи `string s = "acb";`

Компилятор увидел, что мы пытаемся проинициализировать переменную `s` строкой, догадался, что она (переменная) должна иметь тип `string` и подставил его. *И это происходит на этапе компиляции.*

А ваше выражение `var list = (obj is ListBox) ? (ListBox)obj : (MetroComboBox)obj;` вычисляется только во время работы программы. То есть компилятор просто не знает какой тип окажется у переменной `list` и не может его подставить.

Говорая коротко: ошибка возникает потому, что в C# так писать нельзя.

Answer (score -1):

Всем спасибо за разъяснение! Решил проблему данным образом:

```
 dynamic list;
    if (obj is ListBox)
        list = (ListBox)obj;
    else
        list = (MetroComboBox)obj;
```